# Scala UDF for array sorting

Tags: scala

I have a string as below

```
val x = "0=0.5,1=0.3,2=0.2"
```

I want `0=0.5` in the final output. The logic is as below -

`0,1,2` are labels and `0.5,0.3,0.2` are respective probabilities. I want the label and corresponding probabilities for the label that has highest probability.

For example, `0.5` is highest amongst `0.5,0.3 and 0.2` , hence I need `0=0.5` in the output.

Once this function is developed I would like an UDF out of it so that I can use it in downstream processes

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? By "_UDF_", do you mean a _Spark SQL user-defined function_?

Comment: What is the desired result if there is a probability tie: `"0=0.2,1=0.4,2=0.4"`?

Comment: @MikeAllen yes I need a Spark UDF but mostly its the string and array operations so .. I am sorry if the question wasnt asked properly.

Comment: @jwvh , in that case I pick the 1 over 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gets at what you want.

```
x.split(",").maxBy(_.dropWhile(_ != '='))  //res0: String = 0=0.5
```

Note that these are `String` comparisons, so `"2"` is greater than `"12"`, but that's OK since what you're interested in comes after the decimal point.

Comment: can u explain dropWhile operation ?

Comment: Remove everything in front of the `=` (i.e. the "label" part) before making the comparisons to find the max.

Comment: for some reason I am getting the same output as input when I try to wrap that function around a Spark UDF

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a fresh question with the UDF code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Try` to try convert the probability string value to Double and apply `maxBy` to get the first substring with the highest probability value:

```
import scala.util.Try

val x = "0=0.5,1=0.3,2=0.2,3=0.5,4=abc"

x.split(",").maxBy( s =>
  Try(s.split("=")(1).toDouble).getOrElse(Double.MinValue)
)
// res1: String = 0=0.5
```

Note that any non-numeric probability value will be converted to `Double.MinValue`.